# WordPress REST API - New Category returning undefined, but still accessible

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress, rest

I am working with the WordPress REST API and have added a new category, and when querying the api, it is returning undefined for that category.

When I visit: `/wp-json/wp/v2/categories` — the list does not show category 17, but when I visit `/wp-json/wp/v2/categories/17` I can see all the category details.

I can't work out why, is it cached somehow?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`/categories` returns all the fields that exist for a category object. So once you define the category, it will return all the details as you experienced. Without the specific category defined, I think you may find that it's not ignoring category 17 so much as it is stopping after returning 10. If you don't specify the amount to return, it defaults to 10 ([List Categories > per_page](http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/categories/)).

To retrieve a list of all categories, use [`/taxonomies/category`](http://v2.wp-api.org/reference/taxonomies/) or specific your per_page to `-1`

Comment: Hey amflare - ahh makes sense. Have tried /wp-json/wp/v2/taxonomies/category, and it doesn't return all the categories.Neither do I get them all with /wp-json/wp/v2/categories?filter[per_page]=-1. Am I being stupid :S

Comment: Make sure you are not limiting yourself to only non-empty categories.